# VaR backtesting: counting the number of rejections

Tags: garch, finance, risk, coverage-probability

Let's say you calculate the number of VaR rejections for every $r_{1,t}$, $r_{2,t}$,
should you have the same number of rejections in a model, irrespectively of the weights being different?

$[w,\ 1-w] [r_{1,t} r_{2,t}]^T \leq -[w,\ 1-w][\mu_{1}\ \mu_{2}]^T-\sqrt{[w,\ 1-w] \Sigma  [w,\ 1-w]^T }$
To the left are the actual P\&L and on the right the Value-at-Risk.

Comment: Here at Cross Validated, the [tag:var] tag is for vector autoregression (VAR), not Value at Risk (VaR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, the value at risk ($\text{VaR}$) of a portfolio is generally not the same as the sum of $\text{VaR}$s of the individual elements. E.g. let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be returns on two assets. Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ follow a bivariate normal distribution with standard normal marginals and a correlation approaching negative one, $\rho\approx-1$. Construct a portfolio with equal weights, $w_1=1$ and $w_2=1$. Denote its return $r_p$:
$$
r_p:=r_1+r_2.
$$
Since $r_p$ is a linear combination of two marginals from a bivariate normal distribution, it is normally distributed itself. Note that
\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}(r) &= \text{Var}(w_1 r_1) + \text{Var}(w_2 r_2) + 2\rho\sqrt{\text{Var}(w_1 r_1)\times\text{Var}(w_2 r_2)} \\
&= \text{Var}(r_1) + \text{Var}(r_2) + 2\rho\sqrt{\text{Var}(r_1)\times\text{Var}(r_2)} \\
&\approx 1+1+2(-1)\sqrt{1\times 1} \\
&=0
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}(w_1 r_1) + \text{Var}(w_2 r_2) &= \text{Var}(r_1) + \text{Var}(r_2) \\
&= 1+1 \\
&\approx 2.
\end{aligned}
Thus $r_p$ will be highly concentrated around zero and for any chosen probability $q$, $\text{VaR}_q(r_p)$ will be close to zero, too. Meanwhile, $\text{VaR}_q(w_1 r_1)$ and $\text{VaR}_q(w_2 r_2)$ will not be close to zero for $q$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Yes, essentially you cannot take out the $[, 1−]$ vector out of the square root, to cancel out with the other side.  Thanks once again!

Comment: With weight forecasts, derived from conditional covariance matrix forecasts, can you apply a Value-at-Risk Backtesting though? I have never seen it applied in, say,  minimum variance portfolios.

Comment: @GeorgiosStrat, I am not entirely sure what *backtesting* means, but if it involves rolling window estimation, forecasting VaR out of sample, collecting forecasts from all the windows and assessing the relative frequency of violations, then why not? I think it makes sense. What are your reservations?

Comment: My only reservation is that I have not seen it. I suppose there is additional error from the weights, but that's what is tested overall, at the end of the day. Probably most researchers focus on equal weights to isolate their attention towards the model itself, not the allocation+model.

Comment: @GeorgiosStrat, the need for testing may depend on the goal of the analysis, but it should always make sense to check if the model's predictions are right on average. If not, the model must be lacking.